# Installing GIMP on Mac OsX 10.8.5: There is no application to open the document

Tags: macos, installation, gimp

I'm trying to download and install GIMP on Mac OsX 10.8.5 from [this page](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/).  I've tried both the "Download GIMP 2.8 from gimp.org" and "this link" hyperlinks under "native builds."  The first downloaded a file called gimp-2.8.14.dmg.torrent (6.7 KB).  The second downloaded a file called gimp-2.8.14.man (60.7 MB).  In both cases, if I try to open the file in the finder, I get an error: "There is no application to open the document."  Any ideas why this is happening, and if I am doing something to cause it?

Answer (score 0):

http://download.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.8/osx/gimp-2.8.14.dmg should be the file you need to download. It is a disk image.

See [How do I install an application from a disk image?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/how-do-i-install-an-application-from-a-disk-image) for instructions on how to install it.